# Authentication required to modify a printer- what's the password?

Tags: printing, authentication

I have 12.04 and have 2 printers installed, both wirelessly over my personal network, no printer sharing. When I try to modify the printers I get a window asking for authentication (username and password). For the life of me I cannot think what these might be. At first I thought it might be my Ubuntu account username and password, but I can't get it to work. The printer username and password (admin and access) doesn't work either.

Does anyone know what it is asking for, and how I can turn that off?

Many thanks.

Comment: try the username & password which was set up first (when installing Ubuntu)

Answer (score 9):

You might be affected by [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/system-config-printer/+bug/387970).

Try running

```
gksudo system-config-printer
```

in a terminal window, then setting up the printer

However, if `gksudo` is not found, try:

```
sudo -H system-config-printer
```

Comment: Tried in Ubuntu 12.4.2 and it works. Thanks!

Comment: Tried in Ubuntu 13.10 and it works too.

Comment: I've tried that with the following results:-

Comment: Sorry these results:-(system-config-printer:3620): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 07:26:04.797: gtk_tree_store_insert_after: assertion 'G_NODE (sibling->user_data)->parent == G_NODE (parent->user_data)' failed

(system-config-printer:3620): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 07:26:04.797: gtk_tree_store_set_value: assertion 'VALID_ITER (iter, tree_store)' failed

(system-config-printer:3620): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 07:26:04.797: gtk_tree_store_set_value: assertion 'VALID_ITER (iter, tree_store)' failed

Answer (score 4):

Adding my username to the `lpadmin` group, as [suggested by msanderz](https://askubuntu.com/a/282208/22949), worked for me. Here is how you add yourself to the group:

```bash
sudo usermod -a -G lpadmin YOUR_USERNAME
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it by adding my user name to the group "lpadmin" which allowed me to make changes in the printer. Since I have been trying to solve a different problem for about three days I do not remember exactly what I did. Try googling "ubuntu add user name to groups" for the sudo command to add your user name.