# CUPS "client-error-not-possible"

Tags: 12.04, networking, printing

I have a network printer and my machine recently stopped being able to print, other machines can print fine. Besides [having to use root to change its settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197189/authentication-required-to-modify-a-printer-whats-the-password), when I try to change its settings I get the following error:

`CUPS "client-error-not-possible"`.

Many forum threads suggest installing `smbclient` to solve the issue, but I already have it installed.

Comment: thx, installing `smbclient` worked for me!

Comment: After trying everything... I found this that worked of me : https://askubuntu.com/questions/492200/installing-cp400-printer-gives-client-error-not-possible-error/580982

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to solve my issue by removing the printer and then readding it again using the `system-config-printer` wizard and searching for a new network printer.

Answer (score 9):

Installing `samba`, `smbclient` and running

`sudo sed -i '/^\[global]/aclient max protocol = SMB3' /etc/samba/smb.conf`

did the trick. Not sure if the last part is necessary though.

Comment: On Linux Mint 19. Just installing "samba" and "smbclient" was enough for me: I ran "sudo apt install samba" and "sudo apt install smbclient". I then ran also the printer configuration with sudo, i.e. "sudo system-config-printer", but I don't know if that (running it with sudo) was really necessary.

Comment: on Ubuntu 22.04 installing `smblient` is sufficient

Answer (score 7):

My issue was having entered `lpd://printer.printland.com` instead of just `printer.printland.com` in the Host field of `gnome-printer-config`.

Answer (score 5):

On Ubuntu 19.04, installing the *smbclient* solves the problem.
So, open a terminal and run the following command :

```
sudo apt-get install smbclient
```