# adding printer, Authentication adding printer username password

Tags: networking, printing, samba, 19.04

I am adding the printer from the windows network via samba.

All seems fine:
- I can authenticate the access to the domain, 
- I can see all the printers there. 
- Adding ppa file, which I download from the printer manufacturer website

But I stuck in the last point when I click apply button and see another authentication window which asks just Username and Password (without domain).
[image]

I tried everything and nothing works:

1. Adjust smbd config to have by default the domain name, which I need
2. {user}@{domain}
3. {user}/{domain}
4. {domain}/{user}
5. {user}

Access to cups server works on localhost:631.

Comment: This solution, combined with the advice here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/301623/cups-client-error-not-possible
fixed all my issues.

Comment: This solution, combined with the advice here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/301623/cups-client-error-not-possible
fixed all my issues.

Answer (score 17):

In Ubuntu 19.10 a new problem arises with the previous solution stated, where there is no longer a password being requested but the window freezes.

After digging around I found this solution: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/513983/386631

Taking from the answer:

1. Open the file `/etc/cups/cups-files.conf`.
2. Find the group name at the line containing `SystemGroup` (in Ubuntu it should be `lpadmin`).
3. Add yourself to that group (`sudo usermod -a -G lpadmin your-username`)
4. Apply it (`sudo service cups restart`).

There will still be an authentication dialog, but now if you put your PC's username and password it works.

Comment: This also works in 20.04. Authentication dialog no longer pops up after signing out of desktop environment and signing back in.

Comment: Note that for me, on 20.04, this was the solution but the accepted answer also caused no harm. i.e. I didn't need to change the DefaultAuthValue back for it to work.

Comment: Adding user to `lpadmin` did the trick on Ubuntu 20.10, thanks!

Comment: This also works in 22.04. I used original setting "DefaultAuthType Basic" in 
/etc/cups/cupsd.conf

Answer (score 14):

OK, I figure out, that this is the request of a CUPS server authentication, which by default, has a value `basic` in config. And you have to switch it off by doing the following:

1. sudo nano /etc/cups/cupsd.conf
2. change the value `DefaultAuthType` to `None`
3. sudo service cups restart

No authentication required anymore

Comment: 3. should read `sudo service cups restart`... no `s` at the end of `service`

Comment: Good suggestion 0x539. I edited the answer.

Comment: Even after following these steps and restarting the system, I keep receiving an authentication error when trying to print (a test page). Any suggestions?

Comment: @poomerang hello. This answer resolves the authentication dialog problem.

Comment: as I said, not for me: the print job is "Held for authentication" anyway and there is no combination of user+password that works

Comment: Don't work for me with 20.04, and I'm in the lpadmin group, still ask login and password.

Comment: I don't think that removing auth check is a good approach.

Comment: Its almost like you need a advanced degree to add a printer.